# How to tell if a variable is a complex number or not c++

Tags: c++, complex-numbers

How can I tell if the output of the quadratic equation in my code (t1 and t2) are real or complex? The goal of this program is to take coordinates and velocities of two objects to see if they collide or not. And if the value of t1 or t2 is complex then they don't collide which is why I need help figuring out how to tell if t1 and t2 are complex or not.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cmath>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::string;

int main() {
  string id;
  double x = -34.94;
  double y = -69.13;
  double vx = 0.468;
  double vy = -0.900;
  double x2 = -43.08;
  double y2 = 92.12;
  double vx2 = -0.811;
  double vy2 = -0.958;

  double r1 = x2-x;
  double r2 = y2-y;
  double v1 = vx2-vx;
  double v2 = vy2-vy;

  double b = (2*r1*v1) + (2*r2*v2);

  double a = (v1*v1) + (v2*v2);
  double c = ((r1*r1) + (r2*r2))-100;

  double s = pow(b,2)-(4*a*c);

 double t1 = ((b*-1) + sqrt(s)) / (2*a);
 double t2 = ((b*-1) - sqrt(s)) / (2*a);
}
```

Comment: for quadratic equation, you have to check the sign of delta.

Comment: A `double` value cannot be complex. You might be looking for [`std::complex<double>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/complex).

Comment: Definitely at least consider using `std::complex<double>`; it will likely improve the readability of your code

Answer (score 3):

For a quadratic equation you can just calculate it's discriminant. If it's less than 0 then roots are complex.

```
double s = pow(b,2)-(4*a*c);
if(s < 0) {
 // roots will be complex. no collision 
}
```

Comment: That's so much easier than what I was trying. Thanks!

Comment: `b*b` is often preferable to `pow(b,2)`.

Comment: You have a potential problem with loss of precision.  If `b²` and `4ac` are large and similar, their difference represented as a double may round to zero, even though it "ought" to be small and negative (ie, "just missing").  This may not matter to you if the coefficients are only known approximately anyway.